# What is the maximum number of countries one can pass through in total of 1,236.9 km by car?

Tags: international-travel, where-on-earth, road-trips, factoids

I am only interested in the maximum number of countries one would pass through in a total of 1,236.9 km in any one of the continents by car. Time spent, dates etc are not important. Route does not need to be based on the existing routes or roads or condition of the roads.

For example:

1. start here (0km)
2. pass this country
3. pass this country
4. pass this country
5. finish in this country (1,236.9 km)

Total distance is 1,236.9 km by a car

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for that along a straight line (completely ignoring roads, so “by a car” is not relevant) or something that could be/have been done by car, so following existing/past roads?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Why that distance?

Comment: If the point is crossing borders, not adding new countries, you could go in circles.

Comment: @Midavalo sounds like a question generated by AI...

Answer (score 3):

If the question is “along a straight line”, ignoring roads (so more likely in an aircraft rather than in a car), the answer is at least 12:

[image]

The line is actually less than 1200 km, and goes through:

- Greece
- North Macedonia
- Albania (barely)
- Kosovo (barely)
- Montenegro
- Serbia (barely)
- Bosnia and Herzegovina
- Croatia
- Slovenia
- Austria
- Germany (barely)
- Czechia

I'm not sure there are many places outside the Balkans where you can find that many countries in such a short distance.

If the question is "along actual roads", then I haven't managed more than 8 for now:

[image]

- Albania
- Montenegro
- Bosnia and Herzegovina
- Croatia
- Slovenia
- Austria
- Germany
- Czechia